# Problems using multiple arguments on google sheets using IFTEXT

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, multiple-arguments

I am trying to write a formula using `IFTEXT` on google sheets. What needs to happen is if there no text in the I column, then it will say "Not yet."

If there IS text in the I column but not the K column, it still needs to say "Not yet".

However, if there is text in both the I and K columns, it needs to say "yes".

I have this figured out and working with this formula:

`=IF(ISBLANK(I2),"Not yet",IF(AND(ISTEXT(I2),ISTEXT(K2)),"Yes","Not yet"))`

Now comes the issue - if there is text added to the "Q" column, I need it to change and say "Done". I tried the formula:

`=IF(ISBLANK(I2),"Not yet",IF(AND(ISTEXT(I2),ISTEXT(K2)),"Yes","Not yet", IF(ISTEXT(Q2), "Done"))`

But this returned a message saying

> "#NA - Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3
> arguments, but got 4 arguments."

I feel like I have tried everything to get around this but I can't figure it out. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the logic correctly, the flow is as follows:

```
I2 is text & K2 is text & Q2 is text               ---> Done
I2 is text & K2 is text but Q2 is not text         ---> Yes
I2 is text but K2 is not text (Q2 does not matter) ---> Not yet 
I2 is not text (K2 and Q2 do not matter)           ---> Not yet
```

If this is the logic you are trying to code then this formula shuld work:

```
=if(istext(I2),if(istext(K2),if(istext(Q2),"Done","Yes"),"Not yet"),"Not yet")
```